# vba code to show the time range filter applied on form in report

Tags: ms-access

In my Ms Access form (named frmGesamt) I have a filter where I filter the date ranges from .. to ... (named txtVomAll and txtBisAll) If I click on the 'search' button, the dates with this time filter are displayed. My code is like this:

```
Private Sub cmd_SAll_Click()
Dim strCriteria, task As String

Me.Refresh
If IsNull(Me.txtVomAll) Or 
IsNull(Me.txtBisAll) Then
MsgBox "Please enter date range", 
vbInformation, "date range"
Me.txtVomAll.SetFocus
Else
strCriteria = "([BestellDatum] >= #" & Format(Me.txtVomAll, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [BestellDatum] <= #" & Format(Me.txtBisAll, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)"
task = "select * from 
qryFürFormular where(" & 
strCriteria & ") order by 
[BestellDatum]"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter task

End If
End Sub
```

Now when I press the 'report' button, I want to generate a report with this filter.

I wrote the following code for the on open part of the report:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim frm As Form
Dim strFilter, task As String
Set frm = Forms!frmGesamt
strFilter = ""
If IsNull("" & frm!txtVomAll) Or IsNull("" & frm!txtBisAll) Then
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
Exit Sub

Else

strFilter = "select * from  frmGesamt where [BestellDatum] Like "" & task & " * """"


Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True

End If
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Filter property should not be set to an entire SQL statement, just the filter criteria `[BestellDatum] Like '" & task & "*'"`. But instead of setting report Filter property, use OpenReport WHERE ARGUMENT: `DoCmd.OpenReport "reportname", , , "filter criteria here"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, now I can apply the filter to the report much easier. my code is:

`Private Sub cmd_BerichtAll_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "Alle", acViewPreview, , "[BestellDatum] Between #" & Format(Me.txtVomAll, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me.txtBisAll, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
End Sub`

But now it gives an error if the time range is not selected. Somehow I want to open the report even if txt.VomAll and txt.BisAll are null (I mean,even if no time range is given). How do I do that?

Comment: Either dynamically build criteria with If Then conditional blocks and set string variable to reference in OpenReport or use Nz() function to provide a value if control is null.